# How to find every piece of code in my project that addressing/accessing file system?

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea, design-patterns, file-io

I need to find every place in the code (in Java project) where it somehow treats file system (e.g. creates file, reads file, gets the list of directory files etc.)

What is the most common pattern to do this type of search?
How not to miss something?

---

Also, I'm interested in existence of pattern for accessing file systems. Do I need to do such access over the one specific utility (provider, manager, controller...) class?

*This question may seem too broad, apologies in advance.*

Comment: Do you think the Intellij IDEA-way is sufficient for the moment?

Comment: @LppEdd, I don't know, but it seems that you'd argue on that point.

Answer (score 1):

Might be useful. If you right click on a `package` and choose *Find usages*

[image]

You'll then be able to customize the search criteria to include *Usages of classes and interfaces*

[image]

and **de-select** *Show import statements* (we don't need them!)

[image]

Which in my case produces this result

[image]

You can see all the `class`es' and `interface`s' usages from the `java.nio` will be found!
I think this is the best you can have for now, at least without third-party tools.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this question is nothing to do with design patterns.

- Design patterns are relevant to process of designing your application.
- You seem to be asking about how to analyze a codebase that has already been written.

(But no, there are no common *design patterns* that relate to search.)

---

Assuming that you are actually asking about a method for doing this kind of analysis:

- A good IDE will provide facilities for finding places where specific classes are referenced.  So you can identify the classes (in `java.io`, `java.nio`, etc) that you are interested in, and methodically look at all of the places they are referenced in your code.
- On Linux, Unix, Mac are text tools like `grep` that can be combined with `find` to sift through a codebase.  For example, searching for `import` statements.

But there is no magic bullet that will find "anything related to the file system" in your codebase, and no magic bullet that will infer a pattern or patterns from the way your code does something.  (AFAIK)  It is largely down to you.

Comment: Sorry for being equivocal, but I DID want to combine both sides of my question in one. 

So, becides the main question of "how to find all places in code", I also want to know, if there is the best design for accessing disk system.

Do you know design patterns for accessing file system?

Comment: Possibly the visitor pattern.  However, a better idea is to simply use the patterns implemented / supported by java.io, nio, nio2, etc.  For example, `Files.walk` or `Files.walkFileTree`.